# Delete items from listview

Tags: android, listview

I´ve created a listview with a hardcoded arraylist. I simply want to be able to delete items from the list until I add a "real" arraylist or hashmap. A singelklick shall generate a event which is not important at this stage and a longklick on the item shall first ask if you want to delete the item and if pressed yes delete it. I am very new to android and not good at clickevents and such, how do I manage this? If given code-example related to my code I would be more then greatful. Thanx alot!

The R.layout.bookmarks consist of the listview and all it´s items.

```
public class Bookmarks extends ListActivity
{
private static final String[] ITEMS = { "First item", "Second item",
"Third item", "Fourth item", "Fifth item", "Sixth item", "First item", "First item",
"First item", "First item", "First item", "First item", "First item", "First item",  
 };
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bookmarks);

    final ListView list = getListView();
    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    R.layout.styles, ITEMS));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove element from your array which you wants to delete n after that 
Use 
notfiyDataSetChanged() method.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code , 
 open dialog with two buttons on OnItemLongClickListener when click on  delete button remove element from array and apply notifysetdatachanged to your adapter

listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener()
        {

```
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
                int position, long id)
                   {
            //opendialog();
            return false;
        }

    });
```